# Transaction Reverted by EVM during NFT Minting Process

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, arbitrum

Body:

I am trying to create an NFT minting application using React for the frontend, Express.js for the backend, and Solidity for the smart contract. The smart contract is deployed on the Ethereum blockchain.

When I try to mint an NFT, the transaction fails with the error: "Transaction has been reverted by the EVM."

Here is my Solidity contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@thirdweb-dev/contracts/base/ERC721Base.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

contract HighMonkey is ERC721Base {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    // This is your server's public key
    address public serverAddress = 0x2c2A87FfaeF3C6A063675bCBb3312A47b7e24BF9;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        address _royaltyRecipient,
        uint128 _royaltyBps,
        address _serverAddress
    ) ERC721Base(_name, _symbol, _royaltyRecipient, _royaltyBps) {
        serverAddress = _serverAddress;
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenURI, bytes memory signature) public {
        // This is the message to sign
        bytes32 message = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(to, tokenId, tokenURI));
        bytes32 hash = message.toEthSignedMessageHash();

        // Verify that the message's signer is the owner of the order
        address signer = hash.recover(signature);
        require(signer == serverAddress, "HighMonkey: invalid signature");

        // Mint the token
        _mint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);
    }
}
```

And here is the code in my React application where I call the contract's mint function

```
// Call the mint function of the contract
await contract.methods.mint(walletAddress, 1, url, data.signature).send({ 
  from: walletAddress,
  gas: 50000000, // Setting a fixed gas limit
});
```